# What is wrong with this Hibernate paging mechanism?

Tags: java, hibernate

I made a dynamic batch selector based on the count of rows in the table in order to avoid memory leaks. However, this snippet of code seems to fail to retrieve the **last few thousand rows** in the database.

Essentially, the code is shown below:

```
System.out.println("Loading the query...");
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

int i = 0;
int batch = 5000; //process in batches if table is too big
Long rowCount = (Long) session.createQuery("select count(*) " + cacheDetail.getQuery()).list().get(0);

System.out.println("Starting execution on " + cacheDetail.getQuery());
if (rowCount > batch) {
    List<Object> list = session.createQuery(cacheDetail.getQuery())
            .setFirstResult(i).setMaxResults(batch).list();
    while(list.size() == batch || list.size() < batch){
        i+=batch;
        if (list.size() < batch) {
            list = session.createQuery(cacheDetail.getQuery())
                    .setFirstResult(i).setMaxResults(list.size()).list();
        } else {
            list = session.createQuery(cacheDetail.getQuery())
                    .setFirstResult(i).setMaxResults(batch).list(); 
        }
        //Do some computation, close session
    }
}
```

For clarification, cacheDetail.getQuery() is just a HQL select statement: "FROM tableX".

So where in the code am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are NOT consolidating the result to a single list (`total`), because of which you are fetching only the last result, you can look at the refined code below:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

int i = 0;
int batch = 5000; //process in batches if table is too big
Long rowCount = (Long) session.createQuery("select count(*) " + cacheDetail.getQuery()).list().get(0);

//Create a new list to sum each batch    
List<Object> total = new ArrayList<>();

System.out.println("Starting execution on " + cacheDetail.getQuery());
if (rowCount > batch) {
    List<Object> list = session.createQuery(cacheDetail.getQuery())
            .setFirstResult(i).setMaxResults(batch).list();
    total.addAll(list);

    while(list.size() == batch || list.size() < batch) {
        i+=batch;

        if (list.size() < batch) {
        list = session.createQuery(cacheDetail.getQuery())
                .setFirstResult(i).setMaxResults(list.size()).list();
        } else {
        list = session.createQuery(cacheDetail.getQuery())
                .setFirstResult(i).setMaxResults(batch).list(); 
        }

        total.addAll(list);//add to total
        //Do some computation, close session
    }
} else { //what if row count is less than batch, YOU DID NOT HANDLE
    List<Object> list = session.createQuery(cacheDetail.getQuery())
            .setFirstResult(i).setMaxResults(rowCount).list();
            total.addAll(list);
       //Do some computation, close session
}
```

Comment: I would be careful with `while(total.size() < rowCount)` since if a row is deleted in between the query will never terminate, better use `i` as comparison. I would also move the first query in the while loop. In addition to that the batch processing should not push everything in one list, but process it in between if possible to avoid OutOfMemories. For the query in the else block first and max results are not needed.

Comment: oh, okay, got you point, you can have your logic then for while condition, but but the point is create a new list to total and add each result to it

Comment: Do I have to create a new list and push all of the results into it? I would rather not, as memory is quite delicate. EDIT: And how would I go about using i for comparison? It will be quite tricky seeing as it increments with the batch, and it is being used for the queries as the row pointer.

Comment: What is the purpose of this method ? Are you taking a backup ? Are you returning to an UI or external service ?

Comment: Hello javaguy, please check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input javaguy and ST-DDT. In response to your comments, I am loading hibernate objects into a in-memory distributed map. I combined your solutions and tailored it to something like this (using rowCount itself, which should not make it prone to DB modifications). Seems like it works fine, also would like your inputs:

```
int i = 0;
int batch = 5000; //process in batches if table is too big

Long rowCount = (Long) session.createQuery("select count(*) " + cacheDetail.getQuery()).list().get(0);

System.out.println("Starting execution on " + cacheDetail.getQuery());
if (rowCount > batch) { //do batch processing
    List<Object> list = session.createQuery(cacheDetail.getQuery())
            .setFirstResult(i).setMaxResults(batch).list();
    //Load objects from list to a map   

    while(list.size() == batch){
        i += batch;
        rowCount -= batch;
        list = session.createQuery(cacheDetail.getQuery())
                .setFirstResult(i).setMaxResults(batch).list();
    //Load objects from list to a map

    }
    if (rowCount < batch){
        System.out.println("Loading the last " + rowCount + " records.");
        list = session.createQuery(cacheDetail.getQuery())
                .setFirstResult(i).setMaxResults((int)(long)rowCount).list(); 
   //load objects from list to map
    }

    list = null;
    session.flush();
    session.clear();
}
 //Else, use a non paging mechanism to select from DB (trivial)
```

Though I'm really not keen on using the Total list you posted, as I do not want a duplicate and would rather process it the way ST-DDT said.